# Get the current Intent/activity in Android

Tags: android, service

ALL,

We are switching our application from `Linux/C++` to `Android/Java`. One of the task that we are looking for is to create a Help on our application.

The application we will be working on contains of 1 `main activity` and then a lot of plugins and a lot of 3rd party applications.

What I'm thinking about is to create a service which register itself with the main application and when the user hits the `Help-button` will get the current foreground activity/intent and grab the appropriate section in the help file(s).

However, in order to do so I need to know the current intent/activity that is running in the foreground.

Is there a way to get the name of that activity? Or maybe modify the activity to send some kind of string/id, then grab it inside the service and perform the search by this id inside the help file(s)?

I did Android programming about 5-6 years ago and didn't do any service work...

TIA!

Comment: I don't quite understand what kind of app stucture you are planning to implement. Will you be using fragments for different screens? Are you planning on having multiple Activities?

Comment: @B.Plüster, Unfortunately I have no idea what structure is 3rd party apps have. I know this office is creating different plugins for the main application which are based on the Lifecycle class, We are in controls on how we create those plug-ins and what we put in there, but we will be talking to the autors of the main application to include the possibility of the Help.

Comment: @B.Plüster, also, some stuff are being written as service itself and the `Help` button needs to cover it as well.